# Replace Image with Text on Click

Tags: image, text, onclick

So, basically what I'm looking for is a script that when someone clicks on an image, it gets replaced with text that also includes some hyperlinks. I don't really care if it visually slides in, or gets instantly replaced, just as long as when the text comes up, there's a CLOSE option, that returns to the image.

Is there a jQuery or Javascript option for this that I just can't seem to find?

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me out here. :)

Comment: Based on your comment, you want to be able to show a hidden, transparent div over the top of an image when a user hovers over it.

Comment: How would that be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure CSS to achieve the effect you are talking about. [Here is a a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kW2Mr/) of the below code with a bit of styling added.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.outer:hover .inner-text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-text">
    Here is some text
  </div>

  <img width="100" height="100" src="http://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I found the effect I'm looking for, I just don't know how to recreate it:

http://dribbble.com/

The only thing being I'll have multiple links in place, so each one needs to have the ability to be individually clicked.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm! I didn't realize you could a statement like ".outer:hover .whatever" like that.